# Rotate text without jQuery in JavaScript 6

Tags: javascript, css, text, rotation

I want to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("text").style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
```

But it isn't working, And i want my text to be rotated 360°.
*Technechally* I thought this would work. Any ways without jQuery?

Comment: The closing quote should be after the `)`.

Comment: doing a 360deg rotation is equivalent to a 0deg rotation, which is no rotation at all

Comment: Sorry, That was a typing mishap @FelixKling

Comment: I need the 360° since in the code it would be 90° currently

Comment: It doesn't matter what the current rotation of the element is. A 360 rotation is the same as no rotation. A circle only has 360 degrees You are right, it does *technically* work, but it doesn't produce a visually different result. If you want to actually see a difference, you need a different angle.

Comment: Oh, Okay  @FelixKling

Answer (score 2):

A 360deg rotation is equivalent to a 0deg rotation, which is no rotation at all, this is why you are not seeing anything happen:

```js
document.getElementById('text1').style.transform = 'rotate(45deg)';
document.getElementById('text2').style.transform = 'rotate(360deg)';
```

```css
div {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div id="text1">Hello World (45deg)</div>
<br><br>
<div id="text2">Hello World (360deg)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example seems to work fine as long as you use something other than `360deg` since that's a full rotation and looks identical to the default  `0deg` rotation

```js
document.getElementById("text").style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

#text {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use a class

```js
document.getElementById("text").className = "transformed";
```

```css
#text {
  text-align: center;
}

.transformed {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<p>Rotating text</p>
<p id="text">Text that is rotated</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Rotate(rotatingElement,deg)
{
  let ele =document.getElementById(rotatingElement)
  let propValue = "rotate("+ deg +"deg)"
  ele.style.transform=propValue;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22412366)